# String conversion to Number

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, numbers, converters

I'm writing a programming language in python, and I need to convert a **String** into an **Integer** or a  **Floating Point Number** depending on what the type of the converted value is. I used ternary operators and even created a function that returned the type of a value as a string:

```
def rtrn_as_str(value):
  return str(type(value))[8:-2]
```

and this is the output:

```
>>>rtrn_as_str(123)
'int'
>>>rtrn_as_str('A')
'str'
```

But I couldn't find a way to convert a string into a float or int like in Javascript. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: **depending on what the type of the converted value is** what converted value? You are not doing any conversion. Here your function will return something like `"class <classname>"[8:-2]`. Could you show what you mean in JavaScript?

Comment: @Countour-Integral, in javascript, the code I'm trying to replicate is: Number(numberInAString).

Comment: Also, the function I showed was the function that returns the type of a value as a string, in case anyone wants to use it for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean convert 'str' to int or float either, You can try this ;

```
import ast
number = input("Number : ")
print(type(ast.literal_eval(number)))
```

Output;

```
Number : 3
<class 'int'>

Number : 3.14
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've never used AST before. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you are trying to do, but casting a string into float can be easily done:

```
In [32]: some_string = "1.2"

In [33]: some_string_as_float = float(some_string)
    ...: 

In [34]: print(some_string_as_float)
1.2

In [35]: type(some_string_as_float)
Out[35]: float
```

If you want to try cast it into integer first:

```
In [36]: some_other_string = "1"

In [37]: def cast(string):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         return int(string)
    ...:     except:
    ...:         return float(string)
    ...: 

In [38]: cast(some_string)
Out[38]: 1.2

In [39]: cast(some_other_string)
Out[39]: 1
```